# Which kind of variable is the result of gps.location.lat() (TinyGPSlibrary)

Tags: c++, arduino, gps, arduino-ide

How do I put the information printed by `Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);` line in a variable?

```
void loop(){
    // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
    while (ss.available() > 0){
        gps.encode(ss.read());
        if (gps.location.isUpdated()
        {
            Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
            Serial.print( gps.location.lat(), 6);
            Serial.print( " Longitude= "); 

            Serial.println( gps.location.lng(), 6);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete sample code (compiling, if possible) and learn about the term `variable` in C/C++. I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The object **TinyGPSLocation** of **TinyGPS++** library, described [here](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/src/TinyGPS%2B%2B.h), defines the `lat ()` method in the following way:

```
double lat();
```

So you simply need to assign the result of the function to a `double` variable:

```
double Lat = gps.location.lat();

Serial.print( Lat ); /* default Serial.print for floats: two decimals*/
Serial.print(Lat, 6); /* optional second parameter to print six decimals */

/* do whatever you need with your Lat variable */
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the output came like this
Latitude= 27.69 Longitude= 85.27
i want the output to be someting like this
Latitude= 27.695705 Longitude= 85.276679

Comment: Use `serial.print(Lat, 6);`. In case of floating point parametr, the second parameter represents the number of decimal points (default is two, as you can see).